# Raspberry Pi 3 to Azure IoT Hub can't connect in python

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, azure-iot-hub

I tried lot of articles,But couldn't complete this.I want to send messages from raspberry pi to IOT hub and from IoT hub to Raspberry Pi.

Currently following this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-python-python-c2d

Problem is when executing this code show an error called

```
Error: Time:Fri Feb  1 10:15:13 2019 File:/usr/sdk/src/c/iothub_client/src/iothub_client_core_ll.c Func:IoTHubClientCore_LL_CreateFromConnectionString Line:1463 iotHubName is not found
Error: Time:Fri Feb  1 10:15:13 2019 File:/usr/sdk/src/c/iothub_client/src/iothub_client_core.c Func:create_iothub_instance Line:941 Failure creating iothub handle
Unexpected error IoTHubClient.IoTHubClient, IoTHubClientResult.ERROR from IoTHub
```

code is

```
python SimulatedDevice.py
```

please help me to solve this problem.
I installed python 3.5 to raspberry pi 3

What I want to know is how to use raspberry pi and Iot hub to tutn on led and turn off already on led.Please if you have any idea,tell me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error typically occurs if there's a problem with your connection string - it should look like this:

```
HostName=yourhubname.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=yourdeviceid;SharedAccessKey=yourdevicekey
```

There's also some useful information about library versions in these articles:

- https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/readme.md
- https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/doc/python-devbox-setup.md

Comment: yes this is the problem,I added that connection string to IoT hub connection string.That's the case.Thanks for your help :)